# command.exe batch file: %XIL_SCRIPT_LOC:~0,-1% ? %~dp0?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm Trying to revive an old windows 7 tool to work in Windows 11 under powershell...
What would the PowerShell equivalent look like for the following command.exe batch file?
I get a little bit confused by ~dp0 and %XIL_SCRIPT_LOC:~0,-1%

```
@echo off
REM XIL_SCRIPT_LOC should point to script location
set XIL_SCRIPT_LOC=%~dp0
REM Remove trailing slash
set XIL_SCRIPT_LOC=%XIL_SCRIPT_LOC:~0,-1%
set XILINX=%XIL_SCRIPT_LOC%
set XILINX_DSP=%XILINX%
set PATH=%XILINX%\bin\nt;%XILINX%\lib\nt;%PATH%
REM Unset XIL_SCRIPT_LOC
set XIL_SCRIPT_LOC=
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
# XIL_SCRIPT_LOC should point to script location
$env:XIL_SCRIPT_LOC = %~dp0
# Remove trailing slash
$env:XIL_SCRIPT_LOC = $env:XIL_SCRIPT_LOC:~0,-1%
$env:XILINX         = $env:XIL_SCRIPT_LOC
$env:XILINX_DSP     = $env:XILINX
$env:PATH           = "${XILINX}\bin\nt;${XILINX}\lib\nt;$env:PATH"
# Unset XIL_SCRIPT_LOC
$env:XIL_SCRIPT_LOC = $null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$env:XILINX         = $PSScriptRoot
$env:XILINX_DSP     = $PSScriptRoot
$env:PATH           = "$PSScriptRoot\bin\nt;$PSScriptRoot\lib\nt;$env:PATH"
```

Comment: It is a best practice to be cross-platform ready. `$(Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath 'lib' -AdditionalChildPath 'nt')`